# Recursive call is breaking by loop

Tags: python, recursion

I'm writing this function that takes the coordinates of a given point `(ligne, colonne)` and checks every neighbour of this point, adding them to `piece` if the value of `plateau[x.neighbour][y.neighbour] == plateau[x.given][y.given]`, the value checked is color.
That part is working but the problem I have is that my loop stops at each recursive call, which is needed to check neighbour of any "valid" neighbour, and when the recursive call is finished my loop doesn't continue.

```
def detecter_piece(plateau, ligne, colonne, piece):

    if plateau[ligne][colonne] is None:
        return []
    voisin = [(ligne-1,colonne),(ligne,colonne-1),(ligne+1,colonne),(ligne,colonne+1)]
    piece.add((ligne,colonne))
    for x, y in voisin :
        if (plateau[x][y] == plateau[ligne][colonne]) and ((x,y) not in piece):            
            return detecter_piece(plateau,x,y,piece)
```

Comment: I suspect you need to remove the return on the last line, it is breaking out of the loop on first truthy pass of the if condition on the second to the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Before we can do anything with this code, it needs some readability help (I'm at a disadvantage not knowing French, so the Python needs to be really crisp for me to have any hope at all of being able to figure out what's going on).  Here's a quick pass to add typing and fix all the PEP8 errors.  :)

```
from typing import List, Set, Tuple, TypeVar

Color = TypeVar('Color')


def detecter_piece(
    plateau: List[List[Color]],
    ligne: int,
    colonne: int,
    piece: Set[Tuple[int, int]]
) -> List[None]:
    if plateau[ligne][colonne] is None:
        return []

    voisin = [
        (ligne - 1, colonne),
        (ligne, colonne - 1),
        (ligne + 1, colonne),
        (ligne, colonne + 1)
    ]
    piece.add((ligne, colonne))
    for x, y in voisin:
        if (
            plateau[x][y] == plateau[ligne][colonne]
            and (x, y) not in piece
        ):
            return detecter_piece(plateau, x, y, piece)
    return []
```

The main thing that jumps out at me is that the return value is meaningless (I typed it as `List[None]` and that worked fine because the empty list never gets anything else appended to it).  It looks like `piece` accumulates all of the information (I'm assuming it's a `set` since you `add` instead of `append`ing).

Normally in a recursive function, if the return value *did* mean something, you'd be adding values to it from your recursive calls.  Looking around at where that might be happening showed me what I think is the bug -- you `return` after processing the first neighbor, when you presumably want to process all of them!

Give this a try.  I don't have your data to test it with, but I suspect it's pretty close to what you're trying to do.

```
from typing import List, Set, Tuple, TypeVar

Color = TypeVar('Color')


def detecter_piece(
    plateau: List[List[Color]],
    x: int,
    y: int,
    piece: Set[Tuple[int, int]]
) -> None:
    if plateau[x][y] is None or (x, y) in piece:
        return
    piece.add((x, y))

    for dx, dy in [(-1, 0), (0, -1), (1, 0), (0, 1)]:
        nx, ny = x + dx, y + dy
        if not (nx in range(len(plateau)) and ny in range(len(plateau[0]))):
            continue
        if plateau[x][y] == plateau[nx][ny]:
            detecter_piece(plateau, nx, ny, piece)
```

Comment: Thank you ! It works perfectly so i'm going to look up the way you did. And thank you for the advice on "syntax" ! As a student i have some parameter forced on me for this function, and yes piece is a set ! Thank you again !!!

Comment: Please mark the answer as helpful if it solves your issue :)